# How to use Maxlength in Spring <Form:Input> tag?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, maxlength

I am stuck with issue of setting 'Maxlength' to Spring 'Form:Input' tag. It is not reflecting in HTML

Spring Code:

```
<form:input path="admin[${loop.index}].firstName" id="firstName${loop.index}" cssClass="required"  maxlength="64" />
```

Output in Browser:

```
<input name="admin[0].firstName" type="text" class="required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

Is there any way to set the same (if not prefer CSS or JQuery)?

Comment: The spring code looks good to me, are you sure about your output? From where does `DynamicListHelper_firstName valid` come from?

Comment: will you please share web.xml?

Comment: It comes from some client end plugin but it is not related to Maxlength

Comment: It looks ok...anyway show your spring-servlet.xml and entire jsp or atleast tag imports

Comment: IMPORTS -> 
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

Comment: Change to `<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>` and max length is a property of `<form:input>` [check this:doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html#spring-form.tld.input)

Comment: Ok you want me just to move attribute prefix after URI. HTTP lost during posting it is already there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126057/discussion-between-fatherazrael-and-sam).

Comment: @fatherazrael are you sure that you are checking the same element...because id attribute is missing in browser...Show the entire jsp and spring-servlet.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comment to answer

> Spring `<form input>` tag supports `maxlength` here is the [document](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html#spring-form.tld.input):

Spring tag library supports almost all the jsp attributes with some extra feature to binding which helps us in mapping the values or in validation.

Spring will not manipulate anything which is provided in jsp. It just shows in browser, but before that if any `jQuery` code or `javascript` code is manipulated the tag then it will show the manipulated tag instead of actual.

In your case it may be `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your web.xml file is for JSP 2.0. If you are having problems accessing EL on specific pages try adding the following to the top of the individual JSP page:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

if you are using JSP 2.0 I think that EL is ignored by default so you can can add the following to your web.xml to enable it for all pages:

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <el-enabled>true</el-enabled>
    <scripting-enabled>true</scripting-enabled>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: maxlength is not property in Spring Form Input. We do not have web.xml

Comment: @fatherazrael `maxlength` is a property of Spring Form Input tag. Check the official documentation : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html#spring-form.tld.input

Comment: @fatherazrael Please share spring controller full code